# Mapbox flyTo animation not working on desktop browser

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm doing my first steps with the Mapbox GL API and I'm trying to do a simple flyTo to a specific point in the map.

The issue I'm finding is that I'm trying to display an animation between the initial map state to the point selected but there's no animation at all.

I noticed thought that the animation does work on mobiles.

Is there a way to have that same animation on a desktop browser?

I'm thinking that maybe Mapbox GL JS is not the correct library to be used, but all the documentation I'm reading points me towards it.

PS: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/flyto-options/ I have followed this, but the animation won't work on their example either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapbox GL JS version 1.2.0 introduced a check for [prefers-reduced-motion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion), so that user's who've said to websites that they prefer reduced motion, Mapbox GL JS respects this and doesn't animate transitions.

In https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/8743 we are proposing to add an option that allows the website developer to specify if a considered is considered essential and if so then it will ignore prefers-reduced-motion and animate.

That proposal is at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/8883

For the time being if want to see animation's then don't tell your browser that you prefer reduced motion, that's a bit contradictory.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't understand how this is not clarified on their documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this, lost half an hour trying to find the mistake in my code, and I had enabled "prefers-reduced-motion" in the past on osx to improve performance. Toggling it off fixed it.

Comment: I finally got to say, "It works on my machine" and it really was the client messing with their browser settings.